# How to pass an onClick event handler a function that takes a parameter and still bind the function to the component's "this" context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class based React component called "AllProducts.jsx" that I defined like this "class AllProducts extends Component" so when I pass functions to onClick event handlers, I need to bind the context of "this", but when I try to pass one of these functions a parameter, I get an error in the console that says "cannot read property bind of undefined."

This is what the code looks like when it throws an error, please look at the i tag's onClick handler:

```
renderProductInfo() {

    return this.props.allProducts.map((product) => {
        return [
            <li id="shownName">{product.name}</li>,
            <li id="shownSKU">{product._id}</li>,
            <li id="shownCategory">{product.category}</li>,
            <li id="shownPrice">${product.price}</li>,
            <li id="shownQuantity">{product.quantity}</li>,
            <i onClick={this.handleEditProduct(product._id).bind(this)} 
               id="shownEdit" className="fi-pencil"></i>,
            <br />
        ];
    });

}
```

I worked around this issue by defining the function right inside the onClick handler like this:

```
<i onClick={() => {
                    this.props.fetchSingleProduct(product._id).then(() => {
                        var opposite = !this.state.editProduct;

                        this.setState({
                            editProduct: opposite
                        });
                    });
                }} 
                   id="shownEdit" className="fi-pencil"></i>
```

Is there a way for me to just directly pass in the parameter and avoid the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you normally pass parameters using an arrow function:

```
<i onClick={() => this.handleEditProduct(product._id)} id="shownEdit" className="fi-pencil"></i>
```

Also, this is how you would do it with `.bind`:

```
<i onClick={this.handleEditProduct.bind(this, product._id)} id="shownEdit" className="fi-pencil"></i>
```

You need to call `.bind` on the function, not the return value of the function call. So any parameters would go after the context (first param).

Comment: So how was I calling bind on the value of the function call, I'm not clear on that?

Comment: `this.handleEditProduct` = function.  `this.handleEditProduct(product._id)` = function being called. When you put `.bind` on the function being called, it's trying to call it on whatever `.handleEditProduct` returned (in this case, undefined)

Comment: Whoa, totally makes sense. Thanks for the explanation and answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is calling the function, which leads to an error:

```
onClick={this.handleEditProduct(product._id).bind(this)}
```

This is binding the function with a parameter, which is what you want:

```
onClick={this.handleEditProduct.bind(this, product._id)}
```

Note that the function signature for `handleEditProduct` should be `(productId, event)`.

Comment: What do you mean by function signature? I'm unfamiliar with that term.

Comment: Meaning the parameters that the function takes: since `onClick` is an event handler you will get `(event)` as an argument, and since `bind` prepends arguments you give it you will get `(productId, event)` as arguments.

Comment: So "event" will automatically be passed in 3rd because of the function's signature?

Comment: Yeah basically... `bind()` returns a new function that when called will automatically prepend the additional arguments you passed. So in this case since `onClick` is invoked with an event argument, and you you've used `bind` with the argument `product._id`, when the function is called (imagine the `<i>` element doing something like `this.props.onClick(event)`) you actually get `(productId, event)`.